# elasticsearch mapping parser exception

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, logstash

I'm trying to import a Jmeter test report to an ELK stack (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana).

I'm using :

- ElasticSearch version 6.7.1
- Logstash version 6.7.1
- Kibana version 6.7.1

I'm feeding this .csv to Logstash and importing this data to elasticsearch

```
Label,SampleSize,Average,Median,90% Line,95% Line,99% Line,Min,Max,Error %,Throughput,Received KB/sec,Std Deviation,targethost
myRequest,5,59,58,63,66,66,52,66,0.00%,5.8,12.3,4.87,myHost
```

Here's a table format for more clarity

| Label | SampleSize | Average | Median | 90% Line | 95% Line | 99% Line | Min | Max | Error % | Throughput | Received KB/sec | Std Deviation | targethost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| myRequest | 5 | 59 | 58 | 63 | 66 | 66 | 52 | 66 | 0.00% | 5.8 | 12.3 | 4.87 | myHost |

And I created this mapping in ElasticSearch :

```
PUT jmeter-report
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "90% Line": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "95% Line": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "99% Line": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "Max": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "Median": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "Min": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "Received KB/sec": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "SampleSize": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "Std Deviation": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "Error %": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "Average": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "Throughput": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get this following Error message in Logstash logs :

> [WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"jmeter-report", :_type=>"doc", :routing=>nil}, #LogStash::Event:0x3a7561c3], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"jmeter-report", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"qEXlwHsBSxy0UyVRzKMJ", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [99% Line] of type [long] in document with id 'qEXlwHsBSxy0UyVRzKMJ'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: "99% Line""}}}}}

If I stop and restart Logstash the field in the error message (here "99% Line") won't be the same, it appears to be kind of random

Answer (score 0):

> "reason"=>"For input string: "99% Line"

It is failing to index the header line because it cannot parse the headers as longs.

You could just ignore it, since indexing the header adds no value, or you could drop it in logstash

```
if [message] =~ /99% Line/ { drop {} }
```